# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel VB.NET How to disable select locked values in a worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library in VB.Net on an excel sheet that is protected.  All of the protected settings are working fine except that I cannot set *Select Locked Cells* which shows when you are using the Excel protect sheet interface but I cannot see how to set this to false using the library.  I have tried all of the different values in the protect method but none of them toggle the value.
**Excel protected sheet menu**
[image: Excel protected sheet menu]

Below is the code snippet I am using to get my workSheet, populate some values, and then protect the sheet.  GetWorkSheet is an internal method which will return a WorkSheet object, and invoiceData is a datatable which has the data which is being added to the spreadsheet.

```
Dim newSheet As Worksheet = getWorkSheet(newSheetName)

' Make the current Work Sheet active so that it will be accepting the data.
newSheet.Activate()
newSheet.Unprotect(sheetPassword)
For i As Integer = 1 To invoiceData.Rows(0).ItemArray.Count
    newSheet.Cells(transactionalRow, i) = invoiceData.Rows(0).ItemArray(i - 1)
Next
'work is done so protect it again
newSheet.Protect(sheetPassword, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True)
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very confusing because that property is not set with the `Protect` statement.

After calling your protect statement, issue the following call:

```
ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
```

See this page for the other values for `EnableSelection`: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.enableselection(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Yeah this is the correct answer which I discovered running a macro as Jamison suggested.  Unfortunately I am having a different issue now where the change is taking affect for as long as the excel file is open but upon closing it manually or through the excel.Quit method that particular change is being lost.

Comment: This holds true even 9 years later. The link that was mentioned in the answer, however, is dead though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try recording a macro and setting it to see what kind of code it generates. I used to do that when I was working with the Interop libs.